# What does "in" and "out" mean in arg direction?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

From [this tutorial](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/CustomTypes#Edit_the_XML), I found

```cpp
class Chat : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", "demo.Chat")
    Q_PROPERTY( QStringList users READ users)

signals:
    void userAdded(const QString& user);
    void userRemoved(const QString& user);

    void messageSent(const Message &message);

public slots:
    void addUser(const QString &user);
    void removeUser(const QString &user);

    void sendMessage(const Message &message);

public:
    Chat(QObject* parent = 0);
    virtual ~Chat();

    QStringList users() const;

private:
    QStringList m_users;
};
```

can generate

```xml
......
    <signal name="userRemoved">
      <arg name="user" type="s" direction="out"/>
    </signal>
    <method name="addUser">
      <arg name="user" type="s" direction="in"/>
    </method>
......
```

What does "out" and "in" mean here?

Comment: The appears to be referring to D-Bus Introspection XML outputted by the QT qdbuscpp2xml tool. Please include information like that when you ask questions to help readers understand what you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [D-Bus Tutorial](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html):

> **Methods and Signals**
>
> Each object has members; the two kinds of member are methods and signals. Methods are operations that can be invoked on an object, with optional input (aka arguments or "in parameters") and output (aka return values or "out parameters"). Signals are broadcasts from the object to any interested observers of the object; signals may contain a data payload.

From the [D-Bus Specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html):

> [...] arguments to a method are often termed "in" (which implies sent in the METHOD_CALL), or "out" (which implies returned in the METHOD_RETURN).

---

> The direction element on <arg> may be omitted, in which case it defaults to "in" for method calls and "out" for signals. Signals only allow "out" so while direction may be specified, it's pointless.

The direction property describes wether the argument is input for the function, or output which will be returned to the caller. For signals, only out parameters are allowed. A function may have multiple `out` parameters, you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587906/2865814) for an example.

In your specific case, `userRemoved` is a signal that transmits the new user over the D-Bus, so the `user` argument is the outward facing value.
`addUser` however is a function that will be invoked via D-Bus and `user` will be the input for that, it's an inward facing value that will arrive via D-Bus rather than being sent from this object.